# Build errors ONLY occur when publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces, publish

I'm trying to publish my project which has references to other projects in my solution.

Whenever I build the solution regularly it builds just fine without any errors.

However, whenever I attempt to publish the project I get the message "Build failed".

When I check the output log I see the following 3 errors:

> > C:\Users\MyUsername\Dropbox\Projects\SEO\QualityLinkBuilder\Web\RealestateJobsMigrations\RealestateJobsConfiguration.cs(10,101,10,124):
> >     error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RealestateJobsDbContext'
> >     does not exist in the namespace 'RealestateScraper' (are you missing
> >     an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Users\MyUsername\Dropbox\Projects\SEO\QualityLinkBuilder\Web\RealestateJobsMigrations\RealestateJobsConfiguration.cs(18,56,18,79):
>   error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'RealestateJobsDbContext'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'RealestateScraper' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)
>
> C:\Users\MyUsername\Dropbox\Projects\SEO\QualityLinkBuilder\Web\ViewModels\JobsVm.cs(364,51,364,69):
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClosedRealestateId' could
>   not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

However, I have referenced the project "RealestateScraper" and the class RealestateJobsDbContext&ClosedRealestateId exists in the "RealestateScraper" project root namespace which HAS been marked as using in the locations where the output marked the errors.

(like I previously stated, the project builds fine too when not publishing).

**What could be the issue here?**
I have cleaned&rebuilt but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Note: I'm not showing the code with the errors since it seems to serve no purpose as I am referencing the assemblies in the files correctly (**using RealestateScraper;**)

Comment: try deleting the published folder, I've seen this issue and that fixed it. This is not a proper answer but it might fix your issue.

Comment: I had accidently reset the publish build platform to x86, rather than Any CPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in the RealestateScraper project I was referencing another project .dll at a location where it no longer existed. I updated the reference location and it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this as well- build only failed during publish. Turns out I was using the wrong password for the azure publish and for some reason I cannot explain it would show that the build failed and include some build errors. After correcting the password this was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I could not identify the error itself. I just changed the publish property "pre-compile". I UNchecked it and then I was able to publish my website

Answer (score 0):

I had some compiler if-then statements in a class.  These worked okay when I did a local build, but when publishing they were not interpreted and caused build errors.  I refactored my code to remove the compiler directives and it now publishes.

Example:

```
#if SERVICE
using System.Web
#endif
```

Changed to:

```
using System.Web
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I have the same unresolved problem solution -prog a -prog b completes both the prog and the solution but when I go to publish it gives me error c0246 on using of the project b called in the project a
Help

Comment: Hey @francesco! Welcome to stackoverflow. I would suggest you to add such posts as comment on the question rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these solutions, and they might have contributed, but I was still getting the error.

I was tipped off by a warning.  I had to make this file not read-only within the project, then it worked.

\obj\Release\netcoreapp3.0\PubTmp\Out\web.config